# How to compare two circular sequences in linear time?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

We have two circular sequences, which means there is no start or end in the sequences, how to test if two sequence are equal or not in linear time? I have two circular sequences of E. Coli bacteria with length (4,639,221). I thought about attaching two sample of the first sequence and find the other one in it in linear time, but I was looking for a better idea, using a suffix tree is a suggestion that I think works for this problem.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: @AndréSouzaLemos I thought we can choose a start and concatenate two string along each other and then find the second string in the first one, but I don't know if it's fine or not.

Comment: @Evil Can you please give me a little more explanation?

Comment: Have you considered suffix trees?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus, I didn't know the exact details of suffix tree, the problem would be solved with that, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @Evil Amazing idea, thank you. The problem is not my homework, I work on biology data (circular DNA) and it was one of my problem for my research. Thanks.

Comment: Your own suggestion in the comments seems to work. If $y$ is shorter than $x$, then we find $y$ in a "rotation" of $x$ iff $y$ is a substring of $xx$. You mention you don't know whether that is fine. What is keeping you?

Comment: Yes, your idea is fine, it would be nice to edit your question, include your attempt and the additional information about the purpose for DNA sequences, some approximate lengths, if the case when these are equal is expected often etc. [This link](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/how-do-i-ask-a-good-homework-question) is still good to follow even if this is not a homework.

Comment: @HendrikJan if $y<2*x$, I think my idea would be OK, why should y be less than x? on the other hand, we can choose the longest sequence for repeating and the shortest one for searching, am I wrong?
I thought there might be a better approach, so I asked about it.

Comment: You should edit the question to mention that: e.g., mention that you have a solution that works when they are equal length but you are not sure what to do if one is twice as long or longer than the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with computing the lexicographlcally least circular substrings$^1$ of the both circular sequences and then compare them directly.

Alternatively you can check for the substring $A$ (the first seqience) in the string $BB$ (a concatenation of $B$, the second sequence) circular sequence with itself) using for example the [KMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)$^2$

You might also be interested in the application of the Suffix Trees (also Suffix Arrays) and [this thesis](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~berkri/Theses/Vasarhelyi_2.pdf) reviewing the applications to DNA sequences.

$^{[1]}$<sub>(described in *K. S. Booth. Lexicographically least circular substrings.
Inf. Process. Lett., 10(4/5):240-242, 1980.*, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation#Booth.27s_Algorithm)</sub>
$^{[2]}$<sub>(Donald E. Knuth, James H. Morris, Jr., and Vaughan R. Pratt,  SIAM J. Comput., 6(2), 323–350. *Fast Pattern Matching in Strings*</sub>

Answer (score -2):

Start in first list with a ptr with 1X speed and the second list with 2X speed. They meet at a point after some time if they both are the same lists. From then on, you can check if each of their nodes are the same. 
This is linear in time.

If they dont meet, they are not the same circular lists.

Comment: I think the question is not about checking if two given pointers are at the same circular lists but whether two separate lists are equal, meaning the elements are equal and in the same order.

Comment: Traverse till you get the same elements i.e. till they meet.

Comment: Traverse till you get the same elements i.e. till they meet.  Then check if all the elements from then have the same value. This is what I was trying to say in the answer.

Comment: Ok. How do you know that the start is really the same point at the both lists?

Comment: It is mentioned that they are circular and they have no start or end. So, you can start traversing from any point.

Comment: aaaba and aabaa are equal, but the starting point was unfortunate and will return not equal

Comment: Yeah. I get your point. The algorithm I mentioned assumes that you have a numbers without any repetition, only then will you be able to make that kind of traversal.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding of the question.  There's no reason to think that there is any node in common between the two sequences.  Suppose the input is that one sequence is "ANABAN" and the other sequence is "BANANA".  Those might be stored in completely disjoint locations in memory (so your procedure would say 'they are not the same circular lists'), but the desired answer is 'Yes the latter can be obtained by rotating the former'.